# troubleshooting Logictech K400 on picore

Tags: keyboard

## BACKGROUND

Picore 9.0.3 is installed on a zero-w device per [instructions](https://www.novaspirit.com/2018/01/09/tiny-core-raspberry-pi-zero-w-install/?unapproved=109569&moderation-hash=d1d7c527d37719608d37dc5b70de7a0f#comment-109569).  Key milestones and successes include:

- resizing SD card
- installing wifi that survives reboot
- GUI install

The Logitech K400 is known to work well in most UNIX distros and worked fine in picore's BASH, before the GUI install: it does not seem to work in the GUI.  From picore's BASH:

```
 lsusb
```

returns

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b

 cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

returns

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046d Product=404b Version=0111
N: Name="Logitech K400"
P: Phys=usb-20980000.usb-1:1
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:404B.0004/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds mouse0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=12001f
B: KEY=3007f 0 0 0 0 483ffff 17aff32d bf544446 0 0 ffff0001 130f93 8b17c007 ffff7bfa d941dfff febeffdf ffefffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: REL=1c3
B: ABS=1 0
B: MSC=10
B: LED=1f
```

## RESOURCE LIST (Google Search)

- [evdev does not load](http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php/topic,22208.15.html)

## QUESTIONS

What command line tests can be performed to diagnose and enable the keyboard and trackpad in the GUI?  Please post suggested tests or actionable test questions in answers.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo modprobe evdev
```

Enables the K400 keyboard and trackpad in the PiCore GUI, however, despite:

```
filetool.sh -b
```

does not survive reboot.  To overcome the reboot hurdle add the instruction:

```
echo "sudo modprobe evdev" >> /opt/bootlocal.sh
```

save the instruction to survive reboot:

```
filetool.sh -b
```